# Codemirror (textarea replace) IE compatability issue

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, debugging, codemirror

Going to log this here just in case anyone has a similiar issue.

"Having a bit of a weird issue and I am hoping that someone can point out if I'm making an error before I bug report or something.

In Chrome this works fine, in IE (version 9 or newer) it refuses to display the codemirror editor as long as its within form tags.

Evidence: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/kmtorrkL (Ok in Chrome / Broken in IE) 
form tags yes / form css yes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/kmtorrkL/32/ (Working in chrome and IE but not a form)
form tags no / form css yes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/kmtorrkL/33/ (working in chrome / Broken in IE.
form tags yes / form css no.

https://www.ablueman.co.uk/the/testbench/fourform.php
Evidence its not a quirks issue or otherwise something in jsfiddle.net

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ablueman.co.uk%2Fthe%2Ftestbench%2Ffourform.php
Damn thing validates as well.

If anyone has any ideas I'm all ears."

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(QTA1, {
    mode: "javascript",
    lineNumbers: true
});
```

answer to follow .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone finds this:

It is fixable by using: 
`var whatever = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('theID'), { lineNumbers:true });`
http://jsfiddle.net/ablueman/kmtorrkL/41/

But that means the manual is essentially incorrect and / or the selector is presumably wrong in IE's eyes. You get a undefined error.

Logged a bug report:
https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/2910

http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html
"var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea);"

Comment: There is a little conversation going on about this in the bug report. The gent is saying basically I did it wrong, which is possible. But he makes no mention of how it should be or why it works in other browsers

Comment: Just keeping this up to date. Turns out it was a PICNIC error. The part I thought should have been an ID, is just a variable. So I should be creating a variable that does document.getElementById or just doing it as above. It seems chrome and FF were "just being helpful", where as IE isnt.